# How to find the pattern in text and substract it in r

Tags: r

> text<-c('Epson Korea, a company well-renowned for color printers and
> projectors, showcased a smart glasses powered by Android OS at a local
> **movie theater CGV in Cheongdam-dong, Seoul**, in the morning of
> Wednesday. The smart glasses’ display can be put on a head and its
> wearer can watch a movie while lying down. ')
>
> pattern<-c('movie CGV Cheongdam Seoul')

I wanna substract the sentence from text using only that pattern, like this.

> movie theater CGV in Cheongdam-dong, Seoul

So I tried to use 'grep' and 'substr' but it's not easy.

> pattern2<-c('movie|.* |CGV|.* |Cheongdam|.* |Seoul')
>
> t<-strsplit(text,' ')
>
> m<-grep(pattern2, text)
>
> substr(t,m,attr(m,"match.length"))

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regmatches(text, regexpr('movie.*Seoul', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `sub` function:

```
sub(".*\\b(movie\\b.*\\bSeoul)\\b.*", "\\1", text)
# [1] "movie theater CGV in Cheongdam-dong, Seoul"
```